# www record on DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

On Windows Server 2008 R2, I would need to perform some redirects.

For example, the websites  `www.a.com` and `www.b.com` should redirect to `c.com`. I have been asked to configure an A record for `www` on `c.com` so that `www.a.com` and `www.b.com` can be added as CNAME records to `c.com`.

I'm wondering, since it is already a website and can be accessed through the Internet, is it again required to create an A record for `www`. Are `www` entries required for a website because in another environment I've seen it configured without a `www` entry for a web server.

I'm new to infrastructure managment and need help on this please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to create either a CN or A record for www.c.com.

Ideally you'd only have one A record and use CN's for the rest in case c.com's IP address changes - that way you do not need to change any of the other records, just c.com's A record.

Comment: Thank you. My question is the website is already hosted and can be accessible via internet without the www record on the DNS. Is it possible that one can access the website without the www record entry on the respective DNS server. If yes, then what is the purpose of www record?

Comment: They cannot access it with out the record, if they go to www.XXX.com right now it will be invalid unless you have a wildcard record for that zone which will make *any* arbitrary address.XXX.com match the host specified - generally not a good idea.